# Run AES for 2 rounds

Tags: aes

I am trying to figure out AES in two rounds with 128 keys. If I have a known plaintext and the ciphertext that comes from this procedure. I get another plaintext which is similar to the previous with the difference of only one byte. I don't know the keys. Everything is  128 bits. How much will be the final ciphertext be affected?

I am taking this step by step for the two plaintexts (with one-byte difference) and I see that:

1. XORing with the first key: Only the different byte will change.
2. Byte substitution: Comparing the result of the 2 cases everything will stay the same except form the different byte.
3. Shift byte: The two outcomes will change the same way and the different byte will still be one just in a different place.

(is that correct so far?)

4. Then comes the mixcolumn... Here I am confused as to how much the result will be affected if I compare the two cases.

Any help with that?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so please indicate!

Comment: Yes kelalaka it is. Is it ok?

Comment: It is okay to ask homework here, however, as our current policy we only provide hints on comments not answer.

Comment: Absolutely! I was not expecting a solution. More of a guidance. Thank you for letting me know about the policy though. :)

Comment: You need an empty line in front of the initial value for markdown to recognize a list and format accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

The difference of one byte before *MixColumn* will propagate to the whole column. The goal of this step is to mix the four bytes together to get another four bytes. Look at the definition and try it yourself.

Also, there is some nice property here. There are $256$ possible values for the XOR difference of the two bytes and since *MixColumn* is linear, the XOR difference of the two columns after applying *MixColumn* will be the same as applying *MixColumn* to the difference of the columns before. So there are only $256$ possible values for the entire difference of the two columns after *MixColumn*.

To make it clear: if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the two columns that differ in only one of the four bytes, then there are $256$ values for $C_1 \oplus C_2$, and we have $\mathrm{MC}(C_1 \oplus C_2) = \mathrm{MC}(C_1) \oplus \mathrm{MC}(C_2)$, so only $256$ possible values for $\mathrm{MC}(C_1) \oplus \mathrm{MC}(C_2)$.

I think it's a nice property.

Comment: This is related to the Square attack.